# Negative lookbehind not working with an OR operator in Regex - Python

Tags: python, regex

I have two scenarios to get some information from a log file which has a structure like this:

```
proc format;

2018-04-12T07:45:52,430 INFO  [00000009] :t707982 - 26         
2018-04-12T07:45:52,430 INFO  [00000009] :t707982 - 27         
2018-04-12T07:45:52,433 INFO  [00000009] :t707982 - 35         '0010','0019'="08"
2018-04-12T07:45:52,434 INFO  [00000009] :t707982 - 36         '0005','0007','0011','0013'="09"

NOTE: There were 95219365 observations read from the data set WORK.TESTE1.
2018-04-12T07:55:41,536 INFO  [00000018] :t707982 - NOTE: The data set WORK.TESTE1 has 95219365 observations and 9 variables.
2018-04-12T07:55:41,537 INFO  [00000018] :t707982 - NOTE: Compressing data set WORK.TESTE1 decreased size by 34.04 percent. 
2018-04-12T07:55:41,538 INFO  [00000018] :t707982 -       Compressed is 92230 pages; un-compressed would require 139823 pages.
2018-04-12T07:55:42,230 INFO  [00000018] :t707982 - NOTE: PROCEDURE FORMAT used (Total process time):
2018-04-12T07:55:42,231 INFO  [00000018] :t707982 -       real time           2:07.03
2018-04-12T07:55:42,231 INFO  [00000018] :t707982 -       user cpu time       1:56.98
2018-04-12T07:55:42,231 INFO  [00000018] :t707982 -       system cpu time     39.22 seconds
2018-04-12T07:55:42,231 INFO  [00000018] :t707982 -       memory              3159502.32k

proc format;

2018-04-12T08:45:52,430 INFO  [00000009] :t707982 - 26         
2018-04-12T08:45:52,434 INFO  [00000009] :t707982 - 36         '0005','0007','0011','0013'="09"
NOTE: There were 95219365 observations read from the data set WORK.TESTE2.
2018-04-12T08:55:41,536 INFO  [00000018] :t707982 - NOTE: The data set WORK.TESTE2 has 95219365 observations and 9 variables.
2018-04-12T08:55:41,537 INFO  [00000018] :t707982 - NOTE: Compressing data set WORK.TESTE2 decreased size by 34.04 percent. 
2018-04-12T08:55:41,538 INFO  [00000018] :t707982 -       Compressed is 92230 pages; un-compressed would require 139823 pages.
2018-04-12T08:55:42,230 INFO  [00000018] :t707982 - NOTE: PROCEDURE FORMAT used (Total process time):
2018-04-12T08:55:42,231 INFO  [00000018] :t707982 -       real time           2:07.03
2018-04-12T08:55:42,231 INFO  [00000018] :t707982 -       user cpu time       1:56.98
2018-04-12T08:55:42,231 INFO  [00000018] :t707982 -       system cpu time     39.22 seconds
2018-04-12T08:55:42,231 INFO  [00000018] :t707982 -       memory              3159502.32k
```

**1)** Extract all info between proc {format} and note: procedure {format}

**2)** If the first proc {format} **doesn't** have a note: *procedure {format}*, it needs to stop capturing when it founds another *proc {format}* and not return the *note: procedure {format}* from the second proc {format}, like in this example:

```
proc format;

2018-04-12T07:45:52,430 INFO  [00000009] :t707982 - 26         
2018-04-12T07:45:52,430 INFO  [00000009] :t707982 - 27         
2018-04-12T07:45:52,433 INFO  [00000009] :t707982 - 35         '0010','0019'="08"
2018-04-12T07:45:52,434 INFO  [00000009] :t707982 - 36         '0005','0007','0011','0013'="09"

NOTE: There were 95219365 observations read from the data set WORK.TESTE1.
2018-04-12T07:55:41,536 INFO  [00000018] :t707982 - NOTE: The data set WORK.TESTE1 has 95219365 observations and 9 variables.
2018-04-12T07:55:41,537 INFO  [00000018] :t707982 - NOTE: Compressing data set WORK.TESTE1 decreased size by 34.04 percent. 
2018-04-12T07:55:41,538 INFO  [00000018] :t707982 -       Compressed is 92230 pages; un-compressed would require 139823 pages.


proc format;

2018-04-12T08:45:52,430 INFO  [00000009] :t707982 - 26         
2018-04-12T08:45:52,434 INFO  [00000009] :t707982 - 36         '0005','0007','0011','0013'="09"
NOTE: There were 95219365 observations read from the data set WORK.TESTE2.
2018-04-12T08:55:41,536 INFO  [00000018] :t707982 - NOTE: The data set WORK.TESTE2 has 95219365 observations and 9 variables.
2018-04-12T08:55:41,537 INFO  [00000018] :t707982 - NOTE: Compressing data set WORK.TESTE2 decreased size by 34.04 percent. 
2018-04-12T08:55:41,538 INFO  [00000018] :t707982 -       Compressed is 92230 pages; un-compressed would require 139823 pages.
2018-04-12T08:55:42,230 INFO  [00000018] :t707982 - NOTE: PROCEDURE FORMAT used (Total process time):
2018-04-12T08:55:42,231 INFO  [00000018] :t707982 -       real time           2:07.03
2018-04-12T08:55:42,231 INFO  [00000018] :t707982 -       user cpu time       1:56.98
2018-04-12T08:55:42,231 INFO  [00000018] :t707982 -       system cpu time     39.22 seconds
2018-04-12T08:55:42,231 INFO  [00000018] :t707982 -       memory              3159502.32k
```

So, my problem is with the **second** scenario. My regex keeps capturing the *note: procedure format* from the second *proc format*, while it should ignore the first one and capture only the second case:

```
(?s)(?<=proc[ ])(?P<type>\w+).*?(?:(?<=NOTE:[ ]PROCEDURE[ ])|(?<!=proc[ ]))(?P=type).*?(?=memory)
```

I tried the negative look behind `|(?<!=proc[ ])` with OR operator but still with no success.

[you can see my regex in action here](https://regex101.com/r/qp7hBD/3)

Can you help me?

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on what you want but perhaps this will work: https://regex101.com/r/1ff71u/1

Comment: @Nick It worked! If you want to put it in a answer, i accept it. Thanks so much!

Comment: This is a varient of Nick's reges: `(?s)(?<=proc )(?P<type>\w+?);(?!.+\bproc ).*(?=NOTE: PROCEDURE )`? [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qp7hBD/4). Both employ a negative lookahead to ensure that `'proc'` does not precede  `"NOTE: PROCEDURE"`.

Comment: You don't mention that in your question... It would be helpful if you could clarify the requirements and update the question to include the expected output for each sample input.

Comment: @Nick i just included it in your regex and it worked. Everything ok now. Thanks!

Comment: I've added that to the regex I suggested as well: `r'(?s)(?<=proc )(?P<type>\w+?);(?!.+\bproc ).*(?=NOTE: PROCEDURE (?P<memory>\w+))'`? [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qp7hBD/5).

Comment: @Nick, my apologies. I upvoted you're first comment then upvoted it again. There was a warning messages the second time about me not being able to change it but it wasn't until said OK that I realized what it meant. Despite that, I should be able to sleep tonight.

Comment: @CarySwoveland please don't lose any sleep on my account! :) I didn't even notice...

Answer (score 1):

For that structure of the data, to get the data between `proc {format} and note: procedure {format}` you don't have to use the inline modifier `(?s)` to let the dot match a newline to prevent unnecessary backtracking.

If you want the data in between, you could add a capturing group and instead of using the positive lookbehind at the start, match `proc format;`

To get the data in between, you could match all lines that do not start with either proc format; or contain   `NOTE: PROCEDURE`

The data in between in is capture group 2

```
^proc (?P<type>\w+);\r?\n\s*((?:(?!proc |.* NOTE: PROCEDURE ).*\r?\n)*.*(?= NOTE: PROCEDURE ))
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of line
- `proc`  Match literally
- `(?P<type>\w+);` Named group `type`, match 1+ word chars
- `\r?\n\s*` Match a newline and 0+ whitespace chars
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `(?!proc |.* NOTE: PROCEDURE )` Assert what is directly on the right is not `proc`  or that the line contains  `NOTE: PROCEDURE`
    - `.*\r?\n` Match any char except a newline 0+ times followed by a newline
  - `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times to match all the lines
  - `.*(?= NOTE: PROCEDURE )` Match any char except a newline asserting what is on the right is  `NOTE: PROCEDURE`
- `)` Close group 2

[Regex demo for the first data](https://regex101.com/r/STRQFF/1) | [Regex demo for the second data](https://regex101.com/r/NIqHm9/1)